# Flexslider control not working in a show/hide div

Tags: javascript

I have my slideshow in a show/hide div and just couldn't get the manual controls to work when the hidden div is showed. If I move to another chrome tab and come back to the tab where the flexslider is (div is showing), the controls and the slider work just fine. I'll probably have to re-initialise flexslider but couldn't figure out where exactly in Drupal.

In my theme's script.js I could hide my flexslider with this bit of js:

```
$( '#flexslider-1' ).flexslider({
animation: "slide",
controlNav: true,

start: function( slider ){

$( '#flexslider-1' ).css( 'display', 'none' );

}
});
```

So, I know I can target my flexslider. But how do I go about re-initializing it? Am I thinking right or the problem lies somewhere else? Thanks.

Comment: Are you using behaviors?

Comment: I'm putting my js inside the script.js     Drupal.behaviors.my_custom_behavior = {
  attach: function(context, settings) {

Comment: Please edit your question. But with behavior like that, it should work.